# Using cron job to change a PHP variable with MySQL SELECT query every month

Tags: php, mysql, cron

Okay so I have many scattered pieces of the puzzle. I am trying to make an application that updates the quote at the bottom of my website every month (ie 'Quote of the Month'). I am using PHP to access the MySQL server, and the MySQL server has the quotes in them.

In the database, the table is called 'quotes' and has columns 'quote_id', 'quotation', 'author', and 'datetime_used'. The 'datetime_used' column has a default value of 1991 and I use it to check whether I have used that quote in the last year. If the randomly chosen quote's time is less than the current time minus 1 year, then that quote is used as the new quote of the month. If the quote is used, the 'datetime_used' is updated to current time.

The steps I would think to go through is to:
1. Run a cron job (which would run every month) that does runs the following PHP script:

```
<?php
//Make connection
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","dbname");

//Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

//Run query
//Select random quote
$result = mysqli_query($connect,
"SELECT quotation, author FROM quotes 
    WHERE datetime_used <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
    ORDER BY RAND() 
    LIMIT 1");

$row = $mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$quote = $row['quotation'];

//Update the datetime_used column to NOW()
mysqli_query($connect,"
UPDATE quotes SET datetime_used=NOW() 
    WHERE quotation='$quote'");

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

2. Then include the $quote generated by the cron job script above into my website code:

```
<footer>
<p>Quote of the month: 
<?php
//INCLUDE THE $quote SOMEHOW
echo $quote;
?>
</p>
</footer>
```

So my question is how do I make the cron job update the $quote variable in a way so that I can include the updated variable into my website code. Or is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: The code I came up with that seems to work.

```
<?php
//Make connection
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","test");

//Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($connect)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//Check for month difference between this month and most recently used quote as well as get the quote and author to store
$check = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT MONTH(NOW())-MONTH(datetime_used) AS m, quotation, author FROM quotes ORDER BY datetime_used  DESC LIMIT 1');
$checkarray = mysqli_fetch_array($check);
$quote = $checkarray['quotation'];
$author = $checkarray['author'];
//If the month difference if 1 or greater, it selects a new quote
if ($checkarray['m']) {
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,
    "SELECT quotation, author FROM quotes 
        WHERE datetime_used <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
        ORDER BY RAND() 
        LIMIT 1");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $quote = $row['quotation'];
    $author = $row['author'];

    //Update the datetime_used column to NOW()
    mysqli_query($connect,
    "UPDATE quotes SET datetime_used=NOW() 
        WHERE quotation='$quote' AND author='$author'");
}

mysqli_close($connect);

echo "\"$quote\"
</cite>
-$author";
?>
```

Comment: How do you make it update what variable?

Comment: My mistake. Make it update the $quote variable. 

How do I make the cron job update the $quote variable (ie. into a text file?) so I can use it for my website's footer?

Comment: The quote could be a separate table in MySQL, or you could restructure your quotes to have an indicator, like a field "isQuote", where if it is equal to 1, then it is the quote of the month.  Then when a new quote is picked at the beginning of the month, the old quote is set to 0 and the new one is set to 1.

Comment: How should I go about choosing a new quote every month and showing that quote to the website? I looked into events in MySQL but I couldn't think of a way to spit the MySQL output from the event into my website the way it is setup now.

Comment: `Failed to connect to MySQL` would mean nothing to your cron daemon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating the steps required. You should only need to:

- Via php, run a query on page load checking the quotes table for:
- if the current quote was chosen in the last 30 days
- if so, use it
- if not, choose a new quote that has a date not within the past year
- if one found, update the date_used column with the current date

Cron jobs aren't needed. I'm assuming this is a low traffic site, so running the check on every page access is not a performance problem. If you really need to, you can use a caching system to cache the chosen quote and avoid checking the db until thirty days later.

Comment: Oh man. It's interesting how the way a problem is worded can provide the solution or create roadblocks. Thank you so much. This makes more sense and looks way easier to implement.

Comment: No prob. it's fairly common to think of cron for this because it feels like something that needs to be scheduled. But in reality, most sites can afford a simple query to check every page load.

Comment: Honestly I think cron is probably better for this. Why a) put sql in user-facing page, b) have it run anytime any user hits the page, and c) put sql in a user facing page?

Comment: Because it's simple php-based script. Why do you need to involve cron when you already have to have php/mysql involved? It's adding a third party that's not needed and won't travel with the app. If he ever moves the app to a new machine, he better remember to setup the cron jobs. Hope it's not a windows machine, he needs a different scheduler.

Comment: Would lots of users using the website at the same time make the MySQL server really slow or even crash?

Comment: Fair enough. Sold me on the "move machines" bit (and the edit for the low-traffic assumption). To go with your answer, I would also add the option for toggle column (ex. isEnabled or something like that).

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "lots". If this were a high performance site with thousands of users, you should cache the quote you found, expiring the first of next month, using a cache server. memcached is an excellent choice, but you can store in a flat-file, even compile it into an html template, etc. lots of other choices

Comment: Memcached might not be the best route for me. It requires some installation and setting up which I'm not sure I can do and don't want to mess anything up on my live server hosted on Namecheap.com 

I will look into other ways. I managed to make the app work as per suggestion made by @BotskoNet. Really grateful for all you guys' help as well.